# Securely Passing Javascript Variables to PHP (Using AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Before I outline the question, I ask that the answer not be server side validation, however much your heart urges you to do so. Server side validation could not work in this instance, but would work in most other instances. Thanks!

The reason that server side validation will not work is that the script is a game, and it is passing on whether or not the user won the game. Also included is how many coins the user won from playing:

```
if(result == 0){
    menu3.innerHTML = "0 Coins Gained";
    $.post("end.php", {
    coins: 0,
    won: "no",
    }, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    });
...
```

So obviously this passes the amount of coins and if they won using AJAX. However, someone could easily do any number of things such as:

- Change Coin Amount
- Make Their Own Script
- Change Result Number
- Change If They Won

But wait, there's more folks!

Well not really, I'm probably forgetting stuff.

Before releasing a final version of the game, I cant have people sitting there cheating away! And I did forget something, someone could just write a form the sends the data to that php script and then spam the heck out of it, making huge bank in the game.

Also, if it's not clear, I'm a novice, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anything you don't want the user to be able to change has to be kept on the server. The server keeps track of the number of coins, not the client. The client just displays it to the user.

Comment: Keep it in the database or in session variables.

Comment: Since the game is in JavaScript and not PHP, I can't keep it in either as it would have to be in some way securely passed from the JavaScript

Comment: The game is in BOTH Javascript and PHP. Javascript provides the user interface, PHP mediates between all the players and makes sure the players aren't cheating.

Comment: Just to note it isn't **exactly** multiplayer, but if people cheat I would lose money, as microtransactions for addons would be thwarted by the cheaters.

Comment: So if it's not multiplayer, it's the player versus the house. It's still the responsibility of the server to validate everything the player sends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the secure data has to be kept on the server, it can't trust anything that comes from the client, because the user can change it. The server should always validate any data sent from the client that could possibly be a cheat.

For instance, if you're programming a card game, you send the client the list of cards in the player's hand (and not any other players' hands, of course, since that would allow them to "peek"). Then when the client sends back "I'm playing the Ace of Spades", the server must check that this card is actually in their hand before processing the request.

As another example, if you're programming a game that involves rolling dice, that has to be done on the server, and the server has to calculate the result. It sends the result to the client, which displays it to the user. If that gives the user choices of actions, the client displays a menu (or some other control), and sends the choice back to the server. The server then validates that this is an available choice for the user.

You can keep this information in PHP session variables while the player is logged in. For longer-term storage, like the player's bank and history of games played, you would normally use a database.

Comment: So basically instead of sending the result, send the beginning and the process, and see if it matches up?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You send the user's action, and the server figures out what the result is.

Comment: I will do this as it must be the only solution, thank you!